# Inactive tab opacity (materialTopTabnavigator)

Tags: reactjs, tabs, focus, native, opacity

I have done a TopTabNavigator, and I set a background on One tab.
I want to know how can I remove the opacity when this tab is inactive.

I tried to do a condition with the same `backgroundColor` when focused or not.

Could anyone guide me how to approach this issue?

```
 tabBarLabel: ({focused}) => (
  focused ? 
  <View 
  style={{backgroundColor:'#FF6D70', height: 30, width: 60, justifyContent: 'center', 
  borderBottomLeftRadius: 10, borderBottomRightRadius: 10, marginLeft: 1}}>
    <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize: 10, textAlign: 'center'}}>dashboard</Text>
  </View> : 
    <View 
    style={{backgroundColor:'#FF6D70', height: 30, width: 60, justifyContent: 'center', 
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 10, borderBottomRightRadius: 10, marginLeft: 1}}>
      <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize: 10, textAlign: 'center'}}>dashboard</Text>
    </View> ),
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html).
There is a attribute called **pressOpacity** under **tabBarOptions**. May this helps you.

```
createMaterialTopTabNavigator({ /** Screens */ }, {
  tabBarOptions:{
     pressOpacity: 1 // Some value for pressed tab
     ... // Other Options
  }
  ... // Other Options
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but it's not really what I need. Let me show you screenshots.

That's what I have when I start my App, and I want that the pink button stay pink without opacity when it is inactive.
![Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/2n0buLh.jpg)

[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/gsuAhVj.jpg)